# Shell script Global variable failed in jenkins

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins, sh

I have to assign one path to global variable in shell script for Linux, but it contain space in directory name (abc xyz). I try with "abc\ xyz" it is sucessfully work in comand prompt. But when I try with jenkins it get's failed.

Comment: try this "abc xyz" . enclose your path with double quote without using any escape charactors.

Comment: Thanks Mahi, But it's not work